# Replaced HTML doesn't get executed after replace with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement a lazy-load for YouTube videos on my webpage. For this, I have an a-Tag with an iframe-code of YouTube in HTML-comments in it. Additionally there is an onclick-event, which replaces the comment-tags to activate the YouTube-code.

Here's an example of HMTL:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KC2zbOwbeEs&#038;hd=1" class="video-in-link" style="background:url('http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KC2zbOwbeEs/hqdefault.jpg') no-repeat center center; width:500px; height:281px;" onclick="videoInLink(this);">
<!-- xxltxxiframe width="500" height="281" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KC2zbOwbeEs?fs=1&#038;feature=oembed&#038;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreenxxgtxxxxltxx/iframexxgtxx -->
</a>
```

Heres the appropriate JS:

```
function videoInLink(anchor){
    anchor.innerHTML = anchor.innerHTML.replace(/xxltxx/gi,'<');
    anchor.innerHTML = anchor.innerHTML.replace(/xxgtxx/gi,'>');
    anchor.innerHTML = anchor.innerHTML.replace(/<!--/,'');
    anchor.innerHTML = anchor.innerHTML.replace(/-->/,'');
    anchor.style.background="none";
    anchor.removeAttribute('href');
    anchor.onclick= null;                                               
    return false;
}
```

Everything is fine in Firefox and Chrome: The content gets replaced and the video starts. in IE8 the replacement seems to happen, too, but the video won't load.

Tried several combinations, without success.

---

OK, Dunhamzzz was right in his thoughts making the code easier. I changed to own functions for each video-provider and the implementation works.
So, IE8 doesn't have not a problem with activating code after execution of JavaScript, IE8 had a problem with my code.

Perhaps I will improve the code later on, but my question itself is answered. Thanks.

Comment: That's a pretty crazy way of doing it, why don't you just write the iframe element in the function instead of that weird search and replace syntax you've made up.

Comment: Problem is, that there are more video providers than just YouTube, all of them with different implementations of their videoplayer

Comment: Well in that case you make different functions for each one, at the very least it saves you having to update all of the video links if a carrier changes its embed code.

Also regarding the issue in IE8 it's probably because you're putting an iframe in an anchor tag, try changing it to a div.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead create the iframe node using javascript,
and append it to the parent instead of doing this innerHTML hack.
One simple example here :
http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/33979/creating-iframe-through-javascript/